# Converting null value to dummy ip address

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table where one of the column is ip address. I need to convert/select any value in that column that has null value to ip address e.g. 0.0.0.0. I have below table schema where ip column is the ip address:

```
hive> desc ad_data;
OK
ad_id string 
id_segment bigint 
ip string 
datecreate string 
action string 
utc_date string 
utc_hour string
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the answer you are looking for is COALESCE.Try this

```
select COALESCE(column, "0.0.0.0.") from ad_data;
```

Comment: This is the error I get: NoViableAltException(290@[]); FAILED: ParseException line 1:25 cannot recognize input near '0.0' '.' ')' in expression specification

Answer (score 0):

This query worked:

select COALESCE(sip, "0.0.0.0.") from ad_data;